# Cannot open viewcontroller - ios F# (performSegue and presentviewcontroller)

Tags: ios, xamarin, f#, segue

I'm trying to simply present a ViewController, however, this doesn't work using the `PerformSegue` method or the `PresentViewController` method, nothing seems to happen. I have verified using the debugger that the correct line of code is reached, I have also verified the names and IDs are correct.

```
namespace Proj

open System

open Foundation
open UIKit

[<Register ("FirstPage")>]
type FirstPage (handle:IntPtr) =
    inherit UIViewController (handle)

    override x.DidReceiveMemoryWarning () =
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning (

    )    

    override x.ViewDidLoad () =
        base.ViewDidLoad ()
        let value = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("type")
        x.View.BackgroundColor <- UIColor.Blue
        if value <> null then 
            if value = "landlord" then 
                let Storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null)
                let viewController = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("landlord_home") :?> UINavigationController
                x.PresentViewController(viewController,true,null)
            else 
                if value = "tenant" then
                    let Storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null)
                    let viewController = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("tinder_interface") :?> BackgroundAnimationViewController
                    x.PresentViewController(viewController,true,null) 

        else 
            x.PerformSegue("goToNameReg",x) 



    override x.ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (toInterfaceOrientation) =
        if UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom = UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone then
           toInterfaceOrientation <> UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown
        else
           true
```

Comment: I notice if the "value" is null, your code will do nothing. Because when it's null, it can't be "landlord" or "tenant", in your first if statement nothing happens. Only when the Value is not null it will perform the segue, can you make it sure?

Comment: So I solved this by moving the code from viewdidload to viewdidappear...apparently this doesn't work in viewdidload in F# even though it does in Swift

Comment: glad you solved it